# How to add textviews in response to button clicks (strings that user enters)?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I want to display underneath my AutoCompleteTextView what the user entered when they press the button beside it. So basically adding a textview in response to button clicks. I have "hello world" displaying where i want them to be right now, but am stuck on how to do this inside a button listener. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Here is an image example of what I am trying to accomplish exactly.

[sample display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izfve.jpg)

my onCreate so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("hello world");

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    //LayoutParams is a class to specify layout properties when adding a view to a layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.addView(textView, layoutParams);
  }
}
```

XML for layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tester.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:text="AutoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="PRESS ME"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
AutocompleteTextView autoTv = (autocompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocompleteTextView);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    String enteredText = autoTv.getText().toString();
    if (!enteredText.isEmpty()) {
      TextView textView = new TextView(this);
      textView.setText(enteredText);

      LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
      //LayoutParams is a class to specify layout properties when adding a view to a layout
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      linearLayout.addView(textView, layoutParams);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't like that whole line. "Non-static method getText() can not be referenced from a static context" is the error

Comment: although playing around with it, the first error overall is it cannot resolve the symbol "autocompleteTextView".

Comment: which seems weird as it is the id of the input

Comment: only error showing now is it won't allow the usage of "this" in the line:

Comment: @skoteinos Replace `this` with `MainActivity.this`

Comment: that fixed that. Last thing now is it says "autoTv" is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final. why is that?

Comment: add this `final AutocompleteTextView autoTv = ...`

Comment: upvote or accept the answer if it solved your problem